# How to resolve the installation error in module in bipio?

Tags: git

I am trying to install bipio github repository,when i give **make install**,it throws following error
./tools/git-setup.sh

module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^
**Error: Cannot find module './lib/debug'**

```
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/selvi/bipio/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mquery/node_modules/debug/index.js:2:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

make: *** [install] Error 8